# Can't start gitlab service

Tags: git, debian, gitlab

I have installed gitlab on one of my debian server. It was running for at least 2 months until now. It just stops running and when i tried to run using the command `sudo service gitlab start` it will give me the following errors.

```
Removing stale Unicorn web server pid. This is most likely caused by the web server crashing the last time it ran.
Removing stale Sidekiq job dispatcher pid. This is most likely caused by Sidekiq crashing the last time it ran.
Starting both the GitLab Unicorn and Sidekiqmaster failed to start, check stderr log for details
.
[: 298: -ne: unexpected operator
GitLab is not running.
```

Do you guys have any idea the cause of this and how to fix it? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [issue 4920](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/4920#issuecomment-23555188):

> The only way this error message could have appeared seems to be that the Sidekiq pid got removed by an outstanding process between [these two lines](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/67cf376d97372a9c175f09a12a8ced9c0f5c036f/lib/support/init.d/gitlab#L67-L68):

```
if [ -f "$sidekiq_pid_path" ]; then
    spid=$(cat "$sidekiq_pid_path")
```

Try stopping everything, and restarting GitLab.

Comment: Hello, Yes- I have tried stopping all the services already, including Sidekiq. But still won't work.

Comment: @ShenLance what version of GitLab are you using?

Comment: @VonC- here is my system/packages info https://www.evernote.com/shard/s214/sh/f020f373-96e7-4b22-9b30-f98dde9413ec/0197a9c7e2de1f387a141d3c711cb4d8

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill all processes run under gitlab user. For me it is "git":

```
pkill -u git
```

After that restart gitlab service again.